# Django-payments: How to keep the Secret Key secret?

Tags: django

I'm using the library [Django-payments](https://django-payments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and want to keep the Paypal, Stripe,.. secret keys out of sight.

How to keep the Secret Key hidden, and not appears in the DEBUG page (setting section) in clear?

```
PAYMENT_VARIANTS    
{'stripe': ('payments.stripe.StripeProvider',
            {'public_key': 'pk_test_i7RTWcR0w8aK3KZB2yEfeGVi',
             'secret_key': 'sk_test_k4aH2sWIisUK0TqtPwdUmJ6o'})}
```

Some others passwords are hidden:

```
SECRET_KEY  u'********************'
```

The production env is set with DEBUG = False. But the testing env would allow anyone in the dev and qa teams to obtain the keys.

Other post advice to move keys from `settings.py` to environment variables. Which I did:

```
if os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"):
    PAYMENT_VARIANTS = {
        'stripe': ('payments.stripe.StripeProvider', {
            'secret_key': os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"),
            'public_key': 'pk_test_k4aH2sWIisUK0TqtPwdUmJ6o'}),
    }
else:
    PAYMENT_VARIANTS = {
        'stripe': ('payments.stripe.StripeProvider', {
            'secret_key': 'sk_test_i7RTWcR0w8aK3KZB2yEfeGVi',
            'public_key': 'pk_test_k4aH2sWIisUK0TqtPwdUmJ6o'}),
    }
```

Putting the KEYS in environment variables is not helping, because it will still appear here.

Thank you!

Ps: these are not actual keys.

Comment: Leo, put those important info on another .py file and import them to your settings, then git ignore these file. Remember to put this on your server too.

Answer (score 5):

Django [automatically hides settings](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/debug.py#L25) if they contain any of the following words:

```
API
TOKEN 
KEY
SECRET
PASS
SIGNATURE
```

Your setting doesn't, so it's not hidden, but you can easily change it to `SECRET_PAYMENT_VARIANTS` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file and save your key in it. Read it with python code so you don't need to keep it in settings.py. Assign the "READ" access to the text file for your project user only on web server by excluding everyone else. But make sure it is under the ownership of the project user so your django files can access it in production. If not satisfied then provide details about your production environment to get answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Django will hide anything where the attribute name or key contains any of a [certain set of words](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#debug). Unfortunately, this set of words is hard-coded and case-sensitive. I take it your application cannot use capitalized keys for `secret_key` and `public_key`.

I'd guess that `stripe` is a key that you *can* change. You'd need to use a capitalized key, e.g. `STRIPE_KEYS`, and the dictionary would be hidden in debug views.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

As django-payments is an external library (https://github.com/mirumee/django-payments) I guess I will need to ask this change as a new feature or do a pull request..